# Python script for automatic background changing in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Could you write(or hint at) a Python script that changes the Ubuntu desktop background automatically from a website(like Flickr or deviantArt)? How can I start the script at startup?

Answer (score 0):

Not python but a direction: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/real-time-earth-wallpaper-for-linux.html